# No se muestran mis <li> [bootstrap]

Tags: bootstrap

Hola como andan? estoy practicando un poco bootstrap y no se porque no se muestran mis < li>

este es mi nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-mb bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Muna Store</a>

  <button type="button" name="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
          Login</a>
      </li>

      <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
          Registro</a>
      </li>

      <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></span>
          Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

y mi resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el NavBar no se ven ninguna, inspeccione pero no encuentro el error.

Estoy siguiendo un curso, lo tengo identico, pero a mi no me funciona.

Comment: Falta ver cómo cargas las dependencias. ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap? ¿En qué orden cargas los scripts?  Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta algo de información. No tengo muy claro que dependencias estás importando, aunque haciendo mis pruebas todo funciona correctamente. La única diferencia que encuentro es la importación de los js. Dependiendo de la versión de boostrap que utilices, puedes ver los ficheros que necesitas añadir a tu código [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/versions/).

En mi caso, lo único que he hecho es añadir las siguientes líneas:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

### Edición tras comentario:

Tienes un error, la clase `navbar-expand-mb` debería ser `navbar-expand-md`. Fianalmente quedaría así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Muna Store</a>

      <button type="button" name="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
              Login</a>
          </li>

          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
              Registro</a>
          </li>

          <li class="navbar-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></span>
              Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Utilizo la version 4.3. Y añadi las lineas correspondientes a esa version. De igual manera, en pantalla grande, sigue mostrandose el boton, y el boton es para cuando la pantalla es chica.

Comment: @gisela he modificado la respuesta tras tu comentario. Espero que ahora funcione.

Comment: Excelente!! Mira vos lo que era :/

Gracias!!!